# PostConstruct Not called jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a jsf page that contains only command link . My backing bean has a post construct method. When I click on command link, my action method gets called but post construct method is not called. Here is code..

**Xhtml page:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="CommonLayout.xhtml" >
            <ui:define name="title">
                Final Page
            </ui:define>
            <ui:define name="content">

                <h:graphicImage value="resources\images\arigatougozaimashita.gif" />

                <h2 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 25px; padding-top: 100px">Thanks !!!</h2>

                <h:form style="text-align: center;padding-bottom: 100px; padding-top: 25px">
                    Click <h:commandLink value="here" action="#{finalPage.action}" /> to return to First Login page.
                </h:form>

            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**Backing bean:**

```
package com.mycompany.newyearchallenge2015;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "finalPage")
@ViewScoped
public class FinalPage implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    public FinalPage() {
    }

    /**
     * @Parameters : No parameters
     * @return : String which tells what's the next page to visit
     * @Description: Called on clicking the next button.
     */
    public String action() {

        return "LoginScreen1?faces-redirect=true";

    }

}
```

Does anybody know why???

Comment: Unless there are some disguised design concerns and if you need to invoke the `init()` method (annotated by `@PostConstruct`) on every single HTTP request, you need to designate your bean using `@RequestScoped` having a request scoped bean. A method decorated by `@PostConstruct` is invoked before the bean is put into service - only once after the bean is created (hereby the constructor is called) and dependency injections take place, if any.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because the bean is ViewScoped and that the bean was already created before the request containing the onClick message is received.

If it's request scoped, I would expect it to behave more like you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewScoped` persists only when you redisplayed the same view. 
When you redirect to another view, `@ViewScoped` bean will be destroyed by end of render response phase. 
I guess that you are using `finalPage` bean only on that view you specify and after redirect to `LoginScreen1` view you are using different bean.